# Merge PDFs using php code

Tags: php, pdf, merge

I want to merge PDFs using php code.
So i have used this code from some site but this code isn't working for me it is giving me error as Class 'PDFMerger' not found..
Output folder is still empty even after execution of this code.
I am running code on localhost using xampp.

```
<?php
    include 'PDFMerger.php';

    $pdf = new PDFMerger;

    $pdf->addPDF('D:/sample/pdf-1.pdf', 'all')
        ->addPDF('D:/sample/pdf-2.pdf', 'all')
        ->addPDF('D:/sample/pdf-3.pdf', 'all')
        ->merge('file', 'D:/output/merged.pdf');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to merge,

```
/**
 * Used to merge list of pdf files to make it one
 * @param  array   $files    array of files which are to be merged
 * @param  string  $action   download is currently we implemented, rest you can modify the code
 * @param  integer $page     number of pages need to fetched from every pdf
 * @param  string  $filename name of file for pdf which is merged one
 * @return void
 */
function merge_pdf($files = [], $action = '', $page = 1, $filename = '')
{
    require base_path('vendor/autoload.php');
    $pdf = new \Jurosh\PDFMerge\PDFMerger;
    foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
        $pdf = $pdf->addPDF($file, $page, $key);
    }
    // call merge, output format `file`
    if ($action == 'download') {
        $pdf->merge('download', $filename);
    }
}
```

Here is documentation [`link`](https://github.com/jurosh/php-pdf-merge)

Comment: The package you are linking to uses outdated dependencies. I would suggest an up to date version. A simple concatenation script which uses FPDI is e.g. available [here](https://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/demos/concatenate-fake/).